# Why does python print two answers?

Tags: python, printing, return

```
    if number > 2 and  number < 100:
        print ("yay")
    else:
        print ("boo")

print(test(394))
```

why does the code give me two different answers? boo and None.

Comment: What is test? and what is number?

Comment: Show your entire `test()` function.

Comment: Assuming that your function definition is something like `def test(number):`, the first thing that is printed comes from the print statement within the function and the second one is the one outside, which prints the return value of the function. As you do not return anything, the return value is `None`.

Answer (score 2):

Your function does not return a value, so printing the result of `test(x)` will always return None. However in the function, it prints the result, so there's no reason to wrap your `test()` in a print statement.

For example, either:

```py
def test(x):
    if x > 2 and x < 100:
        return "yay"
    else:
        return "boo"

print(test(394))
```

or

```py
def test(x):
    if x > 2 and x < 100:
        print("yay")
    else:
        print("boo")

test(394)
```

Answer (score 0):

If we assume that your function is something like,

```
def test(number):
    if number > 2 and  number < 100:
        print ("yay")
    else:
        print ("boo")

print(test(394))
```

Then you are getting two outputs because you have written a `print` statement inside the function and then are printing the function output itself.

This way you would be getting

```
boo
None
```

To fix this either just type `test(394)` instead of `print(test(394))` or do

```
def test(number):
    if number > 2 and  number < 100:
        return "yay"
    else:
        return "boo"

print(test(394))
```

Comment: Yea the function you assumed is right, I just started learning and everything is just new and confusing...

Comment: It's not that I don't want the two outputs, but wanted to know the reasoning behind it. Because for functions in math e.g., f(g(x)), you would get one answer because the value you get from g(x) would be inputted into f(x) to yield one answer. So I thought since test(394) was simply printing and not returning a value, print of test (394) would only give None as the output - instead of both boo and None.So does that mean when I run print (test(394)) python is giving me two values because it is giving me a value for test(394) and print (test(394)) separately?...